# Yii - creating a link from data stored in a table

Tags: php, yii

Ive been trying to think of / find a solution to an issue i have. Im creating a menu system for my Yii app but I need to store part of the items need for creating the URL in a table.
I have a table called system_menu_item:

---------------------------------------------------------------------|
item_id | dis_text     | action        | variables                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 1      | edit article | document/view | array('id'=>$model->arl_id) |

What i was hoping for was:

```
$model = SystemMenuItem::model()->findByPk('1');
$url = yii::app()->createUrl($model->action, $model->variables);
```

This doesn't work.. I tried different ways of doing it all not working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "This doesn't work"?  That's not very helpful, and doesn't tell us anything.  What are var_dump($model) and var_dump($url) after you run this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess the issue is that $model->variables evaluates to a string with the value `array('id'=>$mode->arl_id)`.

An ugly (and dangerous!) hack would be to read this in using [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

A better way would be to probably figure out a different way to store your parameters, and read them into an array after performing your DB query.

Comment: Thank you.. this code did work: `$url = yii::app()->createUrl($model->action, eval('return '.$model->variables.';'));`. I tried eval before but it didn't work, i think i forgot to close the statement. I know the risks of using eval but the field will be closed to everyone but admin.